# android gallery scroll like view pager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-gallery

I have used both Gallery and ViewPager widgets, I am fetching images from web service, 
but I couldn't place them in the ViewPager, but in Gallery it is easy.
I used this tutorial for ViewPager
http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-user-interface-design-horizontal-view-paging/

I want android Gallery widget scroll like the ViewPager scroll,

is this possible, how can I do this.

Comment: Note that the [Gallery widget](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Gallery.html) is now deprecated. You should probably use the ViewPager. If you can edit your question and post the trouble that you had while trying ViewPager we can try to help you get it solved that way.

Comment: @Tim i edited my question, check , how can i dynamically create views and add them , and i also want a click listener

Comment: If you go for ViewPager only it solves the problem, you just need to specify within views of pager(that are layouts actually) what you want to show then handle click event(on particular view).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a bare bones example of the instantiateItem() method for your PagerAdapter that would fill it with image views dynamically.

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem( final View pager, final int position )
{
    //Note: if you do not have a local reference to the context make one and
    //set it to the context that gets passed in to the constructor.
    //Another option might be to use pager.getContext() which is how its
    //done in the tutorial that you linked.
    ImageView mImg = new ImageView(context);

    /*Code to dynamically set your image goes here.
    Exactly what it will be is going to depend on 
    how your images are stored. 
    In this example it would be if the images
    are on the SD card and have filenames
    with incrementing numbers like: (img0.png, img1.png, img2.png etc...)*/

    Bitmap mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(
         Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/img" + position + ".png");
    mImg.setImageBitmap(mBitmap);




    ((ViewPager) collection).addView(mImg, 0);
    return mImg;

}
```

Comment: it works perfectly only one problem I got, I dont know why its not showing fading effect on the right side, it shows fading effect only on the left side, i read some blogs, few had problems that it shows fading only on left and top, need to override method for right (getRightEdgeFading) , any suggestions???